# OpenGL context creation error, Microsoft GDI Generic 1.1 version

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl

I am currently encountering a strange problem on a specific **Dell** laptop.

Our application use Qt `5.14` and some OpenGL `4.3` features and set the `setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)` flag. All drivers are up to date with the Dell platform.

The laptop posses 2 graphics card:

- Intel core i7-1065G7
- Nvidia Geforce MX230

The program will run fine for multiple hours on both GPU no matter the graphic preferences (High performance or power saving). The initial QOpenGLContext is valid with the right format.

At one point the context will changed and we will be switched to an OpenGL 1.1 version coming from microsoft GDI. After this point each time I launch the app the following calls return:

```
glFuncs->glGetString(GL_VENDOR); // Vendor Microsoft Corporation
glFuncs->glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // renderer GDI Generic
glFuncs->glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version 1.1.0
```

It will stay like this until I reboot the computer. During this state other applications such as Google Earth Pro might fail from the same kind of error but some don't. For example the context-info app inside `C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.14.2\opengl\contextinfo` works like a charm and can give proper 4.3 context.

While it's happening the underlying context cannot be converted back to a QWGLNativeContext.

```
nativeHandle().canConvert<QWGLNativeContext>(); // return false
```

From the doc it might lead to a conflict with the opengl32.dll but I am not sure.

An antivirus was running in the background the whole time, turning it off didn't changed the problem once it occurs.

Do you have any idea where the problem can come from ?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Would be good if you updated the question and tags with your Windows version. Just guessing: maybe the driver misbehaved or crashed, and Windows decided to silently put a software renderer in its place. Maybe check the system logs.

Comment: Try changing Preferred Graphics processor in Nvidia settings to High-Performance Nvidia Processor and OpenGL rendering GPU to Nvidia.

Comment: Some software can have very weird side-effects with opengl. Have a look at all the other stuff that is running on that machine. Stuff like remote desktop apps are first suspect, but can be anything. We once had a client where the "nahimic" audio overlay was breaking every opengl app on the system. If you can, try to debug into an opengl app and look for all loaded modules to check if some weird DLLs have been injected.